# Spring Integration - Routing back first message in Splitter List before other messages in List

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a Use Case where we receive a payload via a web service which may contain a single business message or many business messages within.

In our SI flow, we are using a `Splitter` to breakdown the received payload into its different business messages (could be up to 5000 business messages within) and, where the payload contains more than one business message, we use the `Splitter` to also include a response business message at the beginning of the split List. After the split, we then have a `Router` to route the first message in the List (the response business message) to one channel (`response.ch`) which flows back to the web service `Endpoint` as the response, and all other business messages to another channel (`request.jms.ch`) which flow to a `JMSOutboundAdapter` for delivery into an MQ Queue for processing elsewhere.

Simplified, the SI flow looks a bit like this:

```
          ->       ->Splitter->Router->JmsOutboundAdapter (to MQ Queue)
WsEndpoint  Gateway                  |
          <-       <-----------------
```

The idea here is that, the client receives an immediate business message response before all other broken down business request messages are written to the MQ Queue.

When I test this flow, the first response business message is placed in the `response.ch` channel before all other business messages begin to be placed in the `request.jms.ch channel` (as expected) but, the `Gateway` and web service `Endpoint` do NOT pick up the response message before other business messages begin to be written to the MQ Queue...

Any ideas why might this be? And how can I ensure that the response is sent back to the client before the split messages begin to be written to the MQ Queue?

Working with:

```
o.s.i:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.0.0.RC1
o.s.i:spring-integration-jms:4.0.4.RELEASE
```

Cheers,
PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the channel after the splitter an `ExecutorChannel`; that way, as soon as all the split messages have been dispatched to the executor, the original thread will return to the gateway and wait for the reply.

Please note that the [dsl 1.0.0.RELEASE](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/24/spring-integration-java-dsl-1-0-ga-released) is now available.

See the new [line-by-line DSL tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/25/spring-integration-java-dsl-line-by-line-tutorial) (line 15 in the cafe demo does exactly what you need - adds an `ExecutorChannel`).

Comment: That's worked nicely Gary, thanks. To add, I have created the executor with a fixed thread pool size, and then configured a Poller on the Router to poll for n messages every 100ms. This way, I know roughly the response will be sent pretty quickly as one of those n messages within that 100ms poll.

Comment: You don't need a poller/queue channel in this case, the `ExcutorChannel` alone should be sufficient. That tutorial has a queue channel downstream for other reasons.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the Router's Poller configuration but left the executor with a fixed thread pool size (as opposed to a default cached thread pool). The use of the fixed thread pool (with a small-ish max. number of threads) over the cached thread pool certainly makes a difference to how quickly the response business message is processed over the other business messages. Thanks again for your help.